# How to deploy from master to production with minimal effort in gitlab?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, production-environment

I am evaluating the possibility of production branch with Gitlab flow as given here:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/workflow/gitlab_flow.md#production-branch-with-gitlab-flow

Here are some points about our setup:

- There are no feature branches as suggested in Gitlab Flow
- All work is committed directly to master.
- Each developer has his own fork which they rebase before starting off each work-item
- Developers make frequent commits for each work item and make a merge request consisting many commits when they are done.
- Tester pulls work from master and tests it. As a result Tester may have commits from two different merges but he may be only testing one at a time.

So lets assume I created a production branch from master a few days ago.

```
X1--X2--X3(master)
        |
        (prod)
```

After this Ann and Barry have made two merge requests which have been accepted

```
X1--X2--X3--A1--A1--A3-Am--B1-B2-Bm(master)
        |
        (prod)
```

Am and Bm represent the individual merge commits by Ann and Barry

Now tester tests and OKs Ann's changes.

Now I have to move Ann's commits to production. What would be the the neatest way? By neatest, I mean: minimum effort on part of Developer and admin. Ideally i would prefer to take Am and merge it to production, but Gitlab only gives me a cherry-pick option and not a full merge.

Like this:

```
X1--X2--X3--A1--A1--A3-Am--B1-B2-Bm(master)
                       |
                     (prod)
```

OR this

```
X1--X2--X3--A1--A1--A3--Am--B1-B2-Bm(master)
        |
        X3'-A1'-A1'-A3'-Am'(prod)
```

Now let me rewind this scenario. Tester finds a bug in Ann's code and asks for a fix. Ann does it and tester ok's the fix .

```
X1--X2--X3--A1--A1--A3--Am--B1--B2--Bm--A4--Am2(master)
```

Now I would like to take

```
X1--X2--X3--A1--A1--A3--Am--B1--B2--Bm--A4--Am2(master)
        |
        X3'-A1'-A1'-A3'-Am'-A4'-Am2'(prod)
```

Next tester OKs Barry's code so I merge Barry's changes to production

```
X1--X2--X3--A1--A1--A3--Am--B1--B2--Bm--A4--Am2(master)
        |
        X3'-A1'-A1'-A3'-Am'-A4'-Am2'--B1'--B2'--Bm'(prod)
```

Is this feasible and even practical?

What would be the best way to track pending/missing changes to production? I would like to use Gitlabs's "X commits behind master" feature to track this(eg at end of a sprint, if I'm 0 commits behind, it means I have all changes in this sprint). Or is there a better way?

Sorry if my question seems too broad but I really am confused and lost.

Appreciate any guidance that can make my life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same reflexion on gitlab prod workflow.
It seems difficult to implement this workflow with Gitlab CE.

I wanted to make this :

```
 R1-----------R2--R3
 /           /   /
A---B---C---D---E---F ← master
             \
              E---F---G ← new-feature
```

The fact is that Gitlab only allows the possibility to merge the whole branch master to prod or to cherrypick (bad idea).

So i decide to use a (imperfect) production workflow with tags.

```
R1          R2  R3   
A---B---C---D---E---F ← master
             \
              E---F---G ← new-feature
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Going by the lack of replies and your comments, it looks like  this is how I will have to make it work.